# A more convenient way, than 'query', to select MultiIndexed rows, designating partial labels by the name of their index levels?

Tags: python, pandas, select, multi-index

Let's say you have a lot of named index levels -- I'll show 4 here but use your imagination:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A0','A1'], ['B0','B1'],['C0','C1'],['D0','D1']],names=['quack','woof','honk','snarf'])
dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(32).reshape((len(midx), len(columns))),index=midx, columns=columns)
dfmi
                       foo  bar
quack woof honk snarf          
A0    B0   C0   D0       0    1
                D1       2    3
           C1   D0       4    5
                D1       6    7
      B1   C0   D0       8    9
                D1      10   11
           C1   D0      12   13
                D1      14   15
A1    B0   C0   D0      16   17
                D1      18   19
           C1   D0      20   21
                D1      22   23
      B1   C0   D0      24   25
                D1      26   27
           C1   D0      28   29
                D1      30   31
```

Then, somewhere along the line, you forgot which level number the name 'snarf' was associated with, and even how many levels there were, and you'd like to do something like:

`dfmi[dfmi.snarf=='D1']`

except the DataFrame is big so keeping another, `reset_index`ed copy around would take too much space and it would be slow anyway, and, being lazy, you don't want to go look it up, and you don't want to dive into yet another syntax with `query`:

`dfmi.query('snarf'=='D1')`

oops!

`dfmi.query("'snarf'=='D1'")`

oops AGAIN!

```
dfmi.query("snarf=='D1'")
                      foo  bar
quack woof honk snarf          
A0    B0   C0   D1       2    3
           C1   D1       6    7
      B1   C0   D1      10   11
           C1   D1      14   15
A1    B0   C0   D1      18   19
           C1   D1      22   23
      B1   C0   D1      26   27
           C1   D1      30   31
```

Finally!

Comment: `query` is the simplest though IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's more convenient, but one alternative to string based query is to use `index.get_level_values`:

```
dfmi[dfmi.index.get_level_values('snarf') == 'D1']

                       foo  bar
quack woof honk snarf          
A0    B0   C0   D1       2    3
           C1   D1       6    7
      B1   C0   D1      10   11
           C1   D1      14   15
A1    B0   C0   D1      18   19
           C1   D1      22   23
      B1   C0   D1      26   27
           C1   D1      30   31
```

Comment: Except for the "_values" name on that method, I prefer this because it 1) preserves the indexing on the access (contrary to the implied function of "_values"), 2) It permits boolean operations in combination with other conditions to further refine the selection and 3) can be syntactically sugared (in effect) to reach the desired level of 'convenience', by which I mean the "Pythonic" notion of "one, preferred, way to do it".  `query` strikes me as a wart on `pandas`.

Answer (score 2):

If we're looking for corresponding values (equality comparison) within a given level by name, then [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) could work:

```
dfmi.xs('D1', level='snarf', drop_level=False)

                       foo  bar
quack woof honk snarf          
A0    B0   C0   D1       2    3
           C1   D1       6    7
      B1   C0   D1      10   11
           C1   D1      14   15
A1    B0   C0   D1      18   19
           C1   D1      22   23
      B1   C0   D1      26   27
           C1   D1      30   31
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
df = df[df.index.isin(['D1'], level='snarf')]
```

Output:

```
                       foo  bar
quack woof honk snarf          
A0    B0   C0   D1       2    3
           C1   D1       6    7
      B1   C0   D1      10   11
           C1   D1      14   15
A1    B0   C0   D1      18   19
           C1   D1      22   23
      B1   C0   D1      26   27
           C1   D1      30   31
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep a copy of the index

```
inds = dfmi.index.to_frame()
dfmi[inds.snarf == "D1"]
 
#                        foo  bar
# quack woof honk snarf          
# A0    B0   C0   D1       2    3
#            C1   D1       6    7
#       B1   C0   D1      10   11
#            C1   D1      14   15
# A1    B0   C0   D1      18   19
#            C1   D1      22   23
#       B1   C0   D1      26   27
#            C1   D1      30   31
```

Comment: Doesn't that discard the indexing on those columns in the new `DataFrame`, thereby rendering searches no more efficient than would a `reset_index`?